# Binding to Generic UI Element / XAML Interface

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, binding

I have a DrawingImage that I use as a Vector image placeholder.
Further on, there are styles that take that respective DrawingImage and use it as an image in my UserControl custom button.

So far everything was fine, but I just came to realize that my current approach has caused my DrawingImages to be non-reusable, since they have their Brush property hard-bound to the control, they are used in, as follows:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="addIcon">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=ImageBrush, ElementName=addButton}" Geometry="M438.2,0H51.6C23.1,0,0,23.2,0,51.6v386.6c0,28.5,23.2,51.6,51.6,51.6h386.6c28.5,0,51.6-23.2,51.6-51.6V51.6
                    C489.8,23.2,466.6,0,438.2,0z M465.3,438.2c0,14.9-12.2,27.1-27.1,27.1H51.6c-14.9,0-27.1-12.2-27.1-27.1V51.6
                    c0-14.9,12.2-27.1,27.1-27.1h386.6c14.9,0,27.1,12.2,27.1,27.1V438.2z" />
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Path=ImageBrush, ElementName=addButton}" Geometry="M337.4,232.7h-80.3v-80.3c0-6.8-5.5-12.3-12.3-12.3s-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.3v80.3h-80.3c-6.8,0-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.2
                    c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3h80.3v80.3c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3s12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3v-80.3h80.3c6.8,0,12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3
                    C349.7,238.1,344.2,232.7,337.4,232.7z" />
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
```

Now, I was trying to come up with a way to have them bound not directly to the Element, but to some kind of a generic Element (similairly as interfaces work) so that the code would be sure that anything that is bound to it, has got the **Brush Dependency property.**

So far, i failed to find it.

I have also tried by searching through an ancestor, still no luck.

> Is there a more or less common practice to binding to unknown Elements, that have certain dependency properties, without exposing them directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, there is no way to do directly what you ask. The reason is that when you define `DrawingImage` as a resource and then use it as a source for image, then no copies of the resource are created, but instead of this each image looks at the same resource. Therefore, the `DrawingImage` can not have a parent in the visual tree at all, so there is just no control to bind to.

There are two options here. One is to *use a `Geometry` as a resource, not a `DrawingImage`*. Then you can create some `DrawingImage` resources referencing to this `Geometry` and using different colors. Or do not use `DrawingImage` at all, but use the Geometry directly (for example, through the `Path`). Actually, there are so many ways how to use and combine Geometry resources. I give just few examples here:

```
<Window x:Class="FlipControlApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="addIconGeometry" Figures="M337.4,232.7h-80.3v-80.3c0-6.8-5.5-12.3-12.3-12.3s-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.3v80.3h-80.3c-6.8,0-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.2
                c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3h80.3v80.3c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3s12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3v-80.3h80.3c6.8,0,12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3
                C349.7,238.1,344.2,232.7,337.4,232.7z"/>

        <PathGeometry x:Key="iconBorderGeometry" Figures="M438.2,0H51.6C23.1,0,0,23.2,0,51.6v386.6c0,28.5,23.2,51.6,51.6,51.6h386.6c28.5,0,51.6-23.2,51.6-51.6V51.6
                C489.8,23.2,466.6,0,438.2,0z M465.3,438.2c0,14.9-12.2,27.1-27.1,27.1H51.6c-14.9,0-27.1-12.2-27.1-27.1V51.6
                c0-14.9,12.2-27.1,27.1-27.1h386.6c14.9,0,27.1,12.2,27.1,27.1V438.2z"/>

        <GeometryGroup x:Key="addIconWithBorderGeometry">
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="iconBorderGeometry"/>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="addIconGeometry"/>
        </GeometryGroup>

        <DrawingImage x:Key="addIconBlack">
            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="{StaticResource addIconWithBorderGeometry}" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
        </DrawingImage>
    </Window.Resources>

    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <Button Name="addButton0" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Image Source="{StaticResource addIconBlack}"/>
        </Button>

        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Foreground="Blue">
            <Image>
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage>
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}"
                                                 Geometry="{StaticResource addIconGeometry}" />
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </Button>

        <Button Width="100" Height="100" Foreground="Green">
            <Grid>
                <Path Data="{StaticResource iconBorderGeometry}" Fill="Pink" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <Path Data="{StaticResource addIconGeometry}" Fill="Purple" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="15"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name="addBtn" Width="100" Height="100" Foreground="Green">
            <Path Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=addBtn}" Stretch="Uniform">
                <Path.Data>
                    <CombinedGeometry Geometry1="{StaticResource iconBorderGeometry}" Geometry2="{StaticResource addIconGeometry}"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

[image: result]

Another option is to *use whole `Image` as resource* with a `Brush` binding to the some ancestors property. But in this case, it is necessary to use the attribute `x:Shared` and hence the resource must be declared in the compiled resource dictionary (for details see [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Create resource:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Image x:Key="addIconImage2" x:Shared="False">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}"
                            Geometry="M438.2,0H51.6C23.1,0,0,23.2,0,51.6v386.6c0,28.5,23.2,51.6,51.6,51.6h386.6c28.5,0,51.6-23.2,51.6-51.6V51.6
                            C489.8,23.2,466.6,0,438.2,0z M465.3,438.2c0,14.9-12.2,27.1-27.1,27.1H51.6c-14.9,0-27.1-12.2-27.1-27.1V51.6
                            c0-14.9,12.2-27.1,27.1-27.1h386.6c14.9,0,27.1,12.2,27.1,27.1V438.2z" />
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}"
                            Geometry="M337.4,232.7h-80.3v-80.3c0-6.8-5.5-12.3-12.3-12.3s-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.3v80.3h-80.3c-6.8,0-12.3,5.5-12.3,12.2
                            c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3h80.3v80.3c0,6.8,5.5,12.3,12.3,12.3s12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3v-80.3h80.3c6.8,0,12.3-5.5,12.3-12.3
                            C349.7,238.1,344.2,232.7,337.4,232.7z" />
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then use it:

```
<Button Name="addButton3" Width="100" Height="100"
        Content="{StaticResource addIconImage}" Foreground="Red"/>
<Button Name="addButton4" Width="100" Height="100"
        Content="{StaticResource addIconImage}" Foreground="Green"/>
```

Each time you reference to it, new copy will be created.

But the first way is more flexible.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. If you might adding examples for the second part, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you again